# More columns in the INSERT statement than values in the VALUES clause

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlclient

I also don't know how to add the values of comboboxes and gender radio buttons to the database. This is basically for a registration form to insert its values into a database. I also need to display the values of the database on the form from selecting the combobox value.

```
private void Btn_register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //int regNo = Cbox_regNo.Text; //i need to get the values from the combobox
    string fName = Tbox_fName.Text;
    string lName = Tbox_lName.Text;
    string dob = dtp_dob.Text;
    string address = Tbox_address.Text;
    string email = Tbox_email.Text;
    string mPhone = Tbox_mPhone.Text;
    string hPhone = Tbox_hPhone.Text;
    string pName = Tbox_parentName.Text;
    string nic = Tbox_nic.Text;
    string cNumber = Tbox_cntctNumber.Text;

    string connString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\"C:\\Users\\abhin\\Desktop\\Final Project\\Visual Studio\\Final Project\\Final Project\\Student.mdf\";Integrated Security=True";
    string Query = "insert into Registrations (regNo, firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth, gender, address, email, mobilePhone, homePhone, parentName, nic, contactNo) values('"+this.Cbox_regNo.Text+"','" + this.Tbox_fName.Text + "','" + this.Tbox_lName.Text + "','" + this.dtp_dob.Value + "','" + this.Tbox_address.Text + "','" + this.Tbox_email.Text + "','" + this.Tbox_mPhone.Text + "','" + this.Tbox_hPhone.Text + "','" + this.Tbox_parentName.Text + "','" + this.Tbox_nic.Text + "','" + this.Tbox_cntctNumber.Text + "') ;";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    SqlCommand cmdDB  = new SqlCommand(Query, conn);
    SqlDataReader myReader;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        myReader=cmdDB.ExecuteReader();
        MessageBox.Show("Record Added Succesfully", "Register Student", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        while (myReader.Read())
        {

        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: In addition to @marc_s' comment, using parameterized queries will help you pinpoint which parameter you're missing or how arguments don't match.

Comment: Dapper is good for this. Here's an example:   https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2019/02/04/basic-insert-update-delete-with-dapper.aspx

Comment: You only close your connection if you get an error too. You should really have some `with`s in there too.

Comment: I think @Larnu meant you shoud have `using` to close the connection. Also you don't need a reader, you can just do `cmdDB.ExecuteNonQuery();`. And `AttachDbFilename` is a really bad idea, instead create or attach a database normally.

Answer (score -1):

On declaring your “Query” variable you are using  12 column (regNo, firstName…) and 11 value. You need one more value

Comment: Yup. But it's still a really bad way to do this

Comment: What if he wants to do it in a bad way?

Comment: Sure. That's his choice of course.

Comment: I don't know why anybody would WANT to code poorly. As mentioned above, SQL Injection is a really bad practice and it really should be avoided. It would be easy to mess with a system by taking advantage of SQL Injection, so when you're building anything that uses a database, it's really smart to prevent those kinds of problems.